# Azure Ad B2C IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am having an issue, I'm not sure why I'm getting this, Basically, I'm trying to get Azure AD B2C working, this works on my local machine and if I try it on Azure free web hosting it works, however on the on the web host I'm using it doesn't I don't know if this is because of how web hosts work, or whether its something else?

The Domain used has been partially removed for security, but the core errors are still there:

[image]

Also I'm using .Net Core as the backend, And when I type the url into my browser it works, just no on the hosting provider.

//Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

//apsettings.json

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "clientid",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": ".onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientSecret": "",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SiUpIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PwdReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_ProfileEdit",
}
```

Comment: the OpenID Connect metadata endpoint should be in this format: `https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=b2c_1_sign_in`

Comment: Please see edited for my configuration

Comment: So you're using the MSAL library ? Have you followed some tutorials ? Could you add the relevant links please ? So if you run locally with the same config (same policy names etc..), it is working ?

Comment: So I can't find any good tutorials on MSAL, but I am still able to connect using this on my local machine and on the free hosting on Azure.

Comment: what do you mean by free hosting ? free webapp ?

Comment: Azure webapp hosting, free for developers. That's the hosting it works on then also works on my local machine, however does not work on my paid web hosting provider.

Comment: You paid webhosting provider ? Is it not azure ?

Comment: For the actual web hosting no as they are expensive, especially when you don't need it to begin with.

Comment: Turns out its a proxy issue would you know the proxy settings?

Comment: Sorry I dont know, what kind of proxy issue ?

Comment: I think the webhost is plain as day blocking the connection but told me to use proxy setting and gave me the web.config settings but this doesn't appear to have solved anythign

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "Authority" to the appsettings.json. So now it would look like

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_{signup_policy}/v2.0/",
    "Instance": "https://abc.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "asdas",
    "Domain": "abc.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
    "CallbackPath": "/b2csignin",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile"

  },
```

this should fix your issue